# Admissible solutions for waves propagating in a fluid medium obtained from Fast Fourier Transform

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, computational-physics, fourier-transform, flow

Given a two-dimensional pressure distribution $p(x,y)$ in a fluid medium, we can perform Fast Fourier transform to obtain the amplitude and phase spectra. The 2D-FFT (and eventually, the IFFT) decomposes the entire pressure distribution into a sum of waves having different combinations of $(k_x,k_y)$.

My question is, for admissible solutions of wave propagation in fluid medium, is it necessary that each of the combinations $(k_x,k_y)$ should satisfy

$$ k_x^2 + k_y^2 = k^2 $$

Comment: $k_x^2 + k_y^2 = k^2$  is a mathematical relation between length of wave vector and thier components and must always satisfied

Comment: Thank you for your response !

So, if the decomposed field is expressed as a sum as,

$ p(x,y) = A_1*cos(k_x_1 *x + k_y_1 *y) + A_2*cos(k_x_2 *x + k_y_2 *y) + ... $

then, each of the combinations, $ k_x_1^2 + k_y_1^2 = k^2$ , $ k_{x2}^2 + k_y_2^2 = k^2$ ,..., must hold true, right ?

Comment: ${k_{x1}}^2 + {k_{y1}}^2 = {k_1}^2$ and ${k_{x2}}^2 + {k_{y2}}^2 = {k_2}^2$ is correct

Comment: I am really sorry for bothering you.
What I intend to ask is, the effective wavenumber in the fluid medium remains constant at a given frequency, say, $k = (\omega/c)$ , where $c$ is the speed of sound in the fluid medium and is a constant. Assuming that the angular frequency also remains constant, then $k$ becomes a constant. Now if the FFT gives different $(k_x,k_y)$, then will each combination of such wavenumber pairs satisfy $k_x^2 + k_y^2 = k^2$ ? Here, the wavenumber $k$ does not change for a given pressure distribution.

Comment: $k_x^2 + k_y^2 = k^2$ is a mathematical relation and holds for each combination of such wavenumber pairs

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. :)